# Blockchain based database for storing simple records

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bigchaindb, orbitdb

I want to implement a small blockchain based solution that could serve as Patient Management System. The system should be able to track patients and their medical records/reports. Of course, this system would not be deployed somewhere, its just a university project.

So far, I've started tried to do it with Ethereum. I didn't find a solution using it. Then I tried to use OrbitDB cause I saw it on Ethereum's site in Developer Resources page. But after I had done some POC using OrbitDb, I came to know that it doesn’t claim to be a “blockchain database”, but rather a choice for decentralized apps. Then someone suggested me to use BigchainDb, but after reading about it and trying to make a small project using it, I came to know that it wouldn't fit my needs. I have also read about Fluree but didn't tried it yet as I have already wasted 3 months experimenting with others and didn't want to waste more.

So, could you recommend me a Blockchain-based Database that could serve my needs. Also, some sample code, preferably in Node.js would be a great help for me.

Please excuse me if I have written something wrong or if my understanding is wrong. I am new to Blockchain.

Thanks

Comment: should try postgere , as it is a university project it is super easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try IPFS developed at protocol labs

The InterPlanetary File System (IPFS) is a protocol and peer-to-peer network for storing and sharing data in a distributed file system. IPFS uses content-addressing to uniquely identify each file in a global namespace connecting all computing devices.

[here](https://medium.com/@mycoralhealth/learn-to-securely-share-files-on-the-blockchain-with-ipfs-219ee47df54c) is the guide to understand more into ipfs

[here](https://blog.goodaudience.com/ethereum-ipfs-react-dapp-tutorial-pt-1-a9dfd5079491) is a simple dapp using ipfs with ethereum

Comment: Thanks alot. This means that I can use OrbitDB. As given [here](https://ethereum.org/developers/#storage), OrbitDB is built on top of IPFS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Emercoin public blockchain, [subsystem NVS](https://emercoin.com/en/documentation/blockchain-services/emernvs) (Name-Value Storage). It allows upload your data with **name_new** command, update value with **name_update**, and see history of changes with **name_history** command.